# Create multiple <audio> elements to prevent a cut of

Tags: javascript, html, audio, playback, restart

If I trigger an HTML5  element via a button, to make it play, I have the problem that, when I hit the button again, the sample will not be played again (since it's already playing).

If I use: 
`n.pause()
 n.currentTime = 0
  n.play()`

it will be cut of which is also not very nice.

Is there an easy way (I'm kind of a beginner) to create a new audio element and destroy it after it has ended, or even another possibility I might can't think of atm?

Comment: Post your full code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest removing any existing audio elements from your HTML so you can just use Javascript.

Eachtime a user clicks your button

```
<button onclick="playSound();">click me</button>
```

a new instance of Audio object is created.

```
function playSound() {
    var n = new Audio("example.mp3");
    n.play();
}
```

Comment: Wow that was easy! I didn't know that you only need two lines of code for that solution! Working very nice! Thanks!

Do I need to destroy the instances manually later?

Answer (score 0):

You could disable the play button when the audio is playing.  You could also provide a pause or stop button.

I don't think you should create a new audio element.

Comment: It is just a small sound that appears for a few seconds, but in the case the user triggers the sound two times I wanted to have to have the tune playing again without the interruption that happens with pause() and currentTime. Maybe I explained my problem a bit too rough, but the solution of noviewpoint already worked fine for me. Thank you for your answer anyway :)